# Delete not working in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have an app in rails 3 and i run the crud everything is working except the delete link.when i click it it always takes me to the show action and i want it to delete that particular record.below is the codes

VIEW

index.html.erb:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method =>:destroy %></td>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  # DELETE /members/1
  # DELETE /members/1.xml
  def destroy
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    @member.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(members_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

...any help plz..

Answer (score 2):

Check the javascript libraries. in my application I had the same problem because I removed prototype and did not install jquery.

This problem occurs because the DELETE method is emulated via javascript.

Comment: check if the confirm popup apears... and look at javascript folder wicth files are in there and if any of them are empty

Comment: it does not popup and in the javascript folder i only have prototype.js file there

Comment: go to your gem file add this line: ``gem 'jquery-rails'`` after that go to console in your app folder and type: ``rails generate jquery:install`` after that run the server again, and if its possible take a screenshot to show the javascript folder.

Comment: tryin to run 'rails generate jquery:install' but i get this error
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.12/lib/generators/jquery/install/install_generator.rb:7: uninitialized constant Jquery::Rails (NameError)

Comment: did you run ``bundle install`` ??

Comment: i ran the bundle install and that one went succesfully

Comment: It should already have installed jquery, but check [this link](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

Answer (score 0):

destroy is a controller's REST action

**:method =>:delete** not **:method =>:destroy**